# 403 error when deploying Rails app with forked formtastic-bootstrap gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a working, deployable Rails 3.2.2 application in which I use the **formtastic** and **bootstrap-sass** gems (amongst others).
To use the Twitter bootstrap styling in my forms I use the [**formtastic-bootstrap**](https://github.com/cgunther/formtastic-bootstrap/tree/bootstrap2-rails3-2-formtastic-2-1) gem forked by *cgunther*, since *mjbellantoni*'s version is not compatible with Rails 3.2.

my Gemfile:

```
gem 'formtastic-bootstrap', :git => 'https://github.com/cgunther/formtastic-bootstrap.git', :branch => 'bootstrap2-rails3-2-formtastic-2-1'
```

On my local machine this works as expected, but when I deploy my application with capistrano, I get an error:

```
Fetching https://github.com/cgunther/formtastic-bootstrap.git
error: The requested URL returned error: 403
fatal: Could not parse object '4e6a7f50153af805470d43a2bd2c9885a902e4a6'.
Git error: command `git reset --hard 4e6a7f50153af805470d43a2bd2c9885a902e4a6` in directory /var/www/[appname]/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/formtastic-bootstrap-4e6a7f50153a has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/var/www/[appname]/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/formtastic-bootstrap-eabf0533be1e6746fb6d99b57db3fdd7c424275b'
```

This same error occurs when I run a bundle install command on the server while installing the formtastic-bootstrap gem.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

Try change 'https' to 'git' in your Gemfile. It's helped me for another gem.